# Limiting theme to frame (for emacs 24 themes)?

Tags: frames, themes

Is it possible to have separate theme for every emacs frame (for new, emacs 24, themes)?

For old themes, there was color-theme-is-global, but I can't find anything similar for new themes...

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called [Color Theme Buffer Local](https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local), but I've never used it and I'm not sure how stable it is. Maybe you can make it work for frames too.

Comment: I tried it some time ago and couldn't get it to work properly (having said that, I haven't tried really hard then so maybe it's time to revisit).